# What is the difference between these two?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have two sentences that looks almost the same but they differ a bit:
$$a_n > 0$$
A) If $a_n\to\infty$, then  $\sqrt[n]{a_n} > 1$  for almost any n
B) If $a_n\to\infty$, then there is $c>1$ in such way that $\sqrt[n]{a_n} > c$ for almost any n

Now I can easily say that A is false because $a_n=n$, $a_n\to\infty$ but $\sqrt[n]{a_n} = \sqrt[n]{n}  = 1$ for almost any n

I'm not sure if B is the same as A

On the other hand if we look at:
C) If $\sqrt[n]{a_n} > 1$ for almost any n then, $a_n\to\infty$
D) If there is $c>1$ in such way that $\sqrt[n]{a_n} > c$ for almost any n then, $a_n\to\infty$

It looks like in this case both C & D are true

Comment: What do you mean by for almost any $n$?

Comment: @user10444: That means, "for all but a finite number of $n$".

Comment: Why do you think $\sqrt[n]{n}=1$? $\sqrt[4]{4}=\sqrt2$ for example.

Comment: $D$ is true, but $C$ is not. For instance, let $a_n = 2$ for all $n$.

Comment: @TonyK true I actually did meant n and and not $n^n$ cause  $\sqrt[\infty]{\infty} = 1$

Comment: You mean, of course, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]n = 1$.

Comment: @TonyK Yea I meant for almost any n. About your answer if $a_n=2$ then why  $\sqrt[n]{a_n} > 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) true: If $a_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, then $a_n>1$ for almost all $n\in\mathbb N$. Hence, $\sqrt[n]{a_n}>\sqrt[n]{1}=1$ for almost all $n\in\mathbb N$.

b) false: Take $a_n:=n$. Then $a_n\to\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$, i.e. for each $\varepsilon>0$ there existst an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $0\leq\sqrt[n]{n}-1<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$, that is, $\sqrt[n]{n}<1+\varepsilon$ for almost all $n$. If $\sqrt[n]{n}\geq c$ for a.a. $n$ and some $c>1$, we eventually had $c<1+\varepsilon$, and this is a contradiction, if we take $\varepsilon=\frac{c-1}{2}>0$.

c) false: Take $a_n:=2$.

d) true: If $\sqrt[n]{a_n}>c$ for a.a. $n$, then $a_n>c^n$ for a.a. $n$. But since $c>1$, $c^n\to\infty$, and hence $a_n\to\infty$.

Comment: about A isnt $a_n=n$, $a_n\to\infty$ but $\sqrt[n]{a_n} = \sqrt[n]{n}  = 1$ for almost any n?

Comment: No, $\sqrt[n]{n}>\sqrt[n]{1}=1$ for $n\geq 2$. However, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$.

Comment: why is it differ when $n \ge 2$?

Comment: For $n=1$ you have $\sqrt[1]{1}=1$. But for $n\geq 2$, the numbers $\sqrt[n]{n}$ are strictly larger than 1. However, when $n$ goes to $\infty$, they come arbitrarily close to 1, but never equal 1!

Comment: I see thanks for the clarification I dont know how I missed it :) I've been told not to accept right away the answers but I will accept your answer soon enough after people will have their time to comment =] thanks

Comment: Thats a good concept to survive mathematics: Never trust any answers until you are completely convinced. And: There are no stupid questions, only stupid answers! :)